# How can we retrieve data in iOS by JSON parsing?

Tags: ios, iphone, json

I am calling this method in my Application.

```
[flickrRequest callAPIMethodWithPOST:@"flickr.photosets.create" arguments:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:FLICKR_AUTH_TOKEN,@"api_key",albumNAME,@"title",@"13978764555",@"primary_photo_id",@"Uploaded from my iPhone/iPod Touch", @"description", nil]];
```

JSON Response:

```
{ "photoset": { "id": "72157644227295321", "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/122586274@N04\/sets\/72157644227295321\/" }, "stat": "ok" }
```

I am getting this response on my log cat, now the problem is that i want to retrieve this "id" in my application,but i am unable to do this. Please help me in the  way in which i can retrieve this id?

Comment: Why are you unable to retrieve the `id`? What did you do to try and parse the data to turn it into a form you could work with? Have you looked at `NSJSONSerialization`?

Comment: First take response in any dictionary using `NSJSONSerialization` then try this.`[[jsonResponse ObjectForKey:@"photoset"]valueForKey:@"id"];`

Comment: when i am using NSDictionary my application crashes and get the error::  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10acd43e0'

Answer (score 3):

After the data returned from server, you can convert it to NSDictionary

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromServer options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];`
```

Now since id is in the 2nd layer, so you can do

```
NSString *id = [[response objectForKey:@"photoset"] objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Comment: When i am using this code                                    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:(NSData*)inResponseDictionary];
                NSError *error;
                NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];             my application crashes and i am getting this error:     *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11240ab80'
What am i doing wrong please help me out of this??

Comment: It looks like you passed an invalid data to your 2nd line. Make sure you the data returned from 1st line is valid. You can try `if(!error) {2nd line} else {[error localizedDescription];}` that might give you a better idea there the 1st line did not run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you perform the nsjsonserialization in the 
`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` 
method.

You need to create a instance variable in the @interface like this:

```
@interface TheClass: NSObject<NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
    NSMutableData *_responseData;
}
```

And then fetch the data this way:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
    [_responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

}
```

All data hasn't been receieved until the connectionDidfinishLoading method is executed.